# Ignoring duplicated records in picker view swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uipickerview

I am trying to do dynamic picker view which shows extra data whenever I will get new input in data base.

At this moment I am using notification and observer to take care of real time updates. Also I am removing all items from string array to get just one newest record - it is not what i want.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.sizeToFit()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: SEARCH_RESULT, object: nil, queue: nil, using: catchNotificationForSearchResult)
    }

func catchNotificationForSearchResult(_notification: Notification) {
        let _resultSearch = _notification.object as! [Class]

        for _result in _resultSearch {
            _stringArray.removeAll()
             _stringArray.append("AAA : \(_result.aaa), BBB \(_result.bbb), CCC : \(_result.ccc)")
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
```

AppDelegate:

```
 fun test() {
     let _fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Class> = Class.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let _searchResults = try DataBaseController.getContext().fetch(_fetchRequest)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SEARCH_RESULT, object: _searchResults)

        } catch {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }

   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `NotificationCenter` to send messages from a view controller to itself?

Comment: Don't you think `_stringArray.removeAll()` is before the for loop. and  `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` after the for loop.

Comment: @redent84 because I am listening data changes on some intervals. I am sorry test function is is AppDelegate